# Combine files by name and zip

Tags: automator, bash, script, zip

How can I automatically ZIP files with same file names (different extensions) into one ZIP?

For example I have four files

- king.jpg
- king.txt
- queen.jpg
- queen.txt

which would led to

- king.zip (containing king.jpg and king.txt)
- queen.zip (containing queen.jpg and queen.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this with a short bash snippet.

```
p=SOME.CRAZY.STUFF
for i in *; do
    f="${i%.*}"
    if [[ "$p" != "$f" ]]; then
        zip "$f" "$f".*
    fi
    p="$f"
done
```

---

If you are not familiar with Terminal/bash and don't plan to use this too often, you can do the following to use it:

- create a folder where you move all your kings and queens to (and nothing else)
- open Terminal, type `cd` followed by a space, drag the folder you've just created into the Terminal window (release the mouse button once a green cross appears) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- type `p=SOME.CRAZY.STUFF` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- type (or even better copy/paste)

  ```
  for i in *; do f="${i%.*}"; if [[ "$p" != "$f" ]]; then zip "$f" "$f".*; fi; p="$f"; done
  ```

  again followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- (assuming no error message etc was displayed) quit Terminal again

Comment: thanks patrix. this one looks interesting. would you like to expand how to use it.

Comment: I assume you are not familiar with Terminal/bash then? I'll update the answer later (=> when I'm in front of a Mac again).

Answer (score -2):

you can put both into one folder and zip that folder..

otherwise you need to use tar, which is a bit more complicated...